# Connecting to AWS EC2 Win8 Instance from Ubuntu with Remmina

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I'm a real beginner in this subject.
My job wants me to connect to our server on AWS - they have created a Win8 Server there.

I have the DNS, the Username and password - thats all.
I understand its easy if I have a Win machine (like most of the workers here) but I'm running Ubuntu 12.04.

How on earth do I connect to this instance? Say the DNS I have is:
 `ec2-<server>.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com`

Do I need remmina or can I do it from my terminal? I'd like to connect to the server, and see the GUI version of the server's desktop. If it was a linux server it'd be enough for me to connect to the console, but its windows so I figure I need a GUI...

When I try putting the DNS,username,password in Remmina I get this message:

```
Unable to connect to RDP server  <server>.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com
```

Do I need to know something else about the server? Do I need a .pem key? Also - I've read some posts and it was written to check/delete something in the `~/.freerdp/certs` file - but this file doesn't exist on my computer, when I `ls` in my `~/.freerdp/` directory -> its empty.

Please help as I clearly don't know how to connet to the remote server, and sadly I couldn't find any info on connection from Ubuntu to Win8 on AWS.

Bonus help: How do I then install Node.js on that server :)**

**EDIT**

Now when I connect I get this message:

```
Certificate Details:

Subject: CN = WIN-KUFF....
Issuer: CN = WIN-KUFF....

Fingerprint: e4:0f:.......

Accept Certificate? OK/Cancel
```

I press OK and then get the same message of Unable to connect to RDP server..

Comment: Check the security group for this EC2 instance. May be the ports are not opened for your IP address?

Comment: The guy at my work said he added my I.P

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I successfully connected with Windows server in AWS through Remmina on Ubuntu.
My configuration were as below,

---

- Server : Public IP
- Username : Administrator
- Password : ******
- Domain : Public DNS

---

I think the trick is Server and Domain. Insert Public IP and Public DNS you can obtained from AWS Instances page.

Cheers!

Comment: The password can be found through the EC2 console by following AWS [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/WindowsGuide/connecting_to_windows_instance.html#connect-rdp): click connect on the ec2 instance, click "get password", upload private key, click "decrypt"

Answer (score 3):

Steps Should be

1. Ubuntu Dash and search for and select ‘tsclient’ When Terminal
2. Server Client opens, type the AWS DNS , username and password of
       the Windows computer and click ‘Connect’

Node.js you can follow this http://www.hanselman.com/blog/InstallingAndRunningNodejsApplicationsWithinIISOnWindowsAreYouMad.aspx

let me know is that work

Comment: I understand that Ubuntu 12.04 doesn't use tsclient anymore but Remmina instead. tsclient doesn't appear in my dash

Comment: I am on Ubuntu 14.04 and its has by default tsclient On ubuntu 12.04 has Remmina by default let me know is that work for you?

Comment: Yes - as I wrote in the question, I am using Remmina

Comment: I have just tested and my setting are 1: protocol -> RDP 2: Server -> ec2-57.27.21.31.us-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com 3: Username -> Administrator 4:Password -> Mypassword 5: Resolution -> Custom 1024 x 768 and I logged in. Please verify that RDP is allowed for you no pem required and Also ask them about Remote access allowed in Windows firewall

Comment: "Please verify that RDP is allowed for you" - you mean check it with the IIS ? I am sure the problem is on my side and not on the server, because it doesn't even attempt to connect...doesn't matter what I write as the server, and even if I leave the name/password blank - I get the same error after 1 second

Comment: can you send configuration screenshort on 4344553@gmail.com

Comment: need to troubleshot man ... can you check the RDP is open please verify it . telnet ec2-57.27.21.31.us-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com 3389

Comment: This works (telnet) - 
Trying 54.72.177.10...
Connected to ec2-54-72-177-10.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com.
Escape character is '^]'.

Comment: Defiantly something wrong with that Windows machine , Or Credentials.

Comment: Its not related to ubuntu , can you check other people are able to connect using windows ? please try on windows is that works ?

Comment: I sent you a mail @abaid - Thanks!

Comment: So issue in the remote system

Answer (score 0):

Install freerdp package in ubuntu

**sudo apt install freerdp-x11**

After installation run the command

**xfreerdp -g 800x600 -u administrator public-ip**

//here -g for graphical resolution of client